# Rotary Screw Air Compressor

Tags: pneumatic

I have a 50 HP screw compressor that has just began to load and unload within 10 seconds when previously would take between 40 and 60 seconds. Nothing has been added or removed from the system. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like whatever spring/latch mechanism that kept slide valve from cycling too "easily" is broken or worn out - it takes much lower pressure differential to move the slide valve either way as it doesn't resist being pushed by pressure nearly as strongly - the hysteresis of operation is way more shallow than it should be; the element that provided mechanical latching in end positions failed.